# Python Xpath stops reading when bumps into a special character (HTML5 entities & Python)

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I want to fetch data from a `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` html document, indeed, without knowing much about html and encodings.

This is the sting I want to fetch:

```
<title>Tom & Jerry  &raquo; The First Adventure</title>
```

the part of my code that reads it is this:

```
title = tree.xpath('//title/text()')[0]
```

But it will fetch only **'Tom '** as the object of the name/variable `title`

while if the HTML title was

```
<title>Tom &amp; Jerry » The First Adventure</title>
```

it would fetch only **Tom & Jerry**

I suspect the answer is sort, but I don't know how to search it. What do I need to do to make it fetch **Tom & Jerry » The First Adventure**?

Comment: I thought the xpath method was built-in, but because of your comment I dabbled a little more on this and found it was coming from lxml and was working fine. The problem was elsewhere in the code, as described above.

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Please add a proper answer. Do not provide an "answer" by editing the question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The question was why the `xpath` method of the `lxml` module was giving me the string only up to any special character. But I was mistaken. The xpath was reading perfectly the whole string as I wanted. I was then sending this string via an API request and the server could not read the whole string. The simple replace method is the solution to my problem where `&` is replaced with `&amp;` and `»` is replaced with `&raquo;`.